# How to use \graphicspath on Windows? (Miktex)

Tags: miktex

On Linux, to specify a path to use across the document with \includegraphics I simply use

```
\graphicspath{{/home/John\ Francis/Desktop/Report/Pictures/}}
```

I am currently using a Windows machine and that does not work. How should I specify Windows directories? I tried

```
\graphicspath{{C:/Users/John\ Francis/Desktop/Report/Pictures/}}
```

and

```
\graphicspath{{C:\Users\John\ Francis\Desktop\Report\Pictures\}}
```

but it hasn't work.

Answer (score 1):

After some additional research, I found out that if pictures are at the same directory as the .tex file, `\graphicspath{{some_path}}` is unnecessary. Therefore, \includegraphics will just assume that image is placed on the working directory.

Answer (score 0):

\graphicspath{{imagestemplate/}{images/}}

will look at images in two subdirectories under your .tex file path (namely imagestemplate and images)

If you have more than a few images I would not keep them in the root working directory.